# NumberFormatException in a multi-frame GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, converters, numberformatexception

I'm in a rather unique situation based on what I've seen in other's coding. I'm working on a multi-frame GUI for a school project and it has four converters between various units: Mass, Volume, Distance, and Temperature. The problem I run into lies with the Text Listeners for my temperature conversions:

```
private class TempListener implements ActionListener{ 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){ 
        double faren, cels; 
        String text = temperature.getText(); 
        faren = Integer.parseInt(text); 
        cels = (faren-32) * 5/9; 
        rLabelT.setText(Double.toString(cels)); 
    } 
} 

private class Temp1Listener implements ActionListener{ 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){ 
        double faren, cels; 
        String text = temperature1.getText(); 
        cels = Integer.parseInt(text); 
        faren = (cels+32) * 9/5; 
        rLabelT1.setText(Double.toString(faren)); 
    } 
}
```

The Integer.parseInt method catches a NumberFormatException.java and stops it from completing the calculation. Now, this coding is almost identical to a similar program from my textbook with the only edits being the variable type. What I worry about is that the other frames have fully functional calculations based on the same block:

```
private class MassListener implements ActionListener{ 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){ 
        double pounds, kilograms; 
        String text = mass.getText(); 
        pounds = Integer.parseInt(text); 
        kilograms = pounds/2.2; 
        rLabelM.setText(Double.toString(kilograms)); 
    } 
} 
private class VolumeListener implements ActionListener{ 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){ 
        double litres, gallons; 
        String text = volume.getText(); 
        gallons = Integer.parseInt(text); 
        litres = .264 * gallons; 
        rLabelV.setText(Double.toString(litres)); 
    } 
} 
private class DistListener implements ActionListener{ 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){ 
        double miles, kilo; 
        String text = distance.getText(); 
        miles = Integer.parseInt(text); 
        kilo = miles * 1.609; 
        rLabelD.setText(Double.toString(kilo)); 
    } 
}
```

All of these work with EXACTLY the same coding without any errors. How do I fix this? It's the last issue in my code to address.

The code to open the frame that contains the temp conversions:

```
   private class ButtonTListener implements ActionListener{ 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){ 
        JFrame dialogT = new JFrame ("Temperature"); 
        dialogT.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
        dialogT.setBounds(750,650,400,150); 
        dialogT.setVisible(true); 
        iLabelT = new JLabel ("Enter a Temperature in Farenheit: "); 
        oLabelT = new JLabel ("Temperature in Celsius: "); 
        rLabelT = new JLabel ("--"); 
        temperature = new JTextField (5); 
        temperature.addActionListener(new TempListener()); 
        iLabelT1 = new JLabel ("Enter a Temperature in Celsius: "); 
        oLabelT1 = new JLabel ("Temperature in Farenheit: "); 
        rLabelT1 = new JLabel ("--"); 
        temperature1 = new JTextField (5); 
        temperature.addActionListener(new Temp1Listener()); 
        Temperature1 = new JPanel(); 
        Temperature1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (400,100)); 
        Temperature1.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        Temperature1.setBackground (Color.yellow); 
        Temperature1.add(iLabelT); 
        Temperature1.add(temperature); 
        Temperature1.add(oLabelT); 
        Temperature1.add(rLabelT); 
        Temperature1.add(iLabelT1); 
        Temperature1.add(temperature1); 
        Temperature1.add(oLabelT1); 
        Temperature1.add(rLabelT1); 
        dialogT.getContentPane().add(Temperature1); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is the text on which `Integer.parseInt` throws a `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: Why `Integer.parse` when the values `mile` and `kilo` are `double`?

Comment: In Java, the integer division `5/9` is `0`, and `9/5` is `1`.  Use `double` literals instead.

Comment: Try to use `Double` values everywhere. The error probably comes from a constellation like: `Integer.parseInt(Double.toString(1.0));`

Comment: @rgettman just bad style with no harm in this case, but `faren` and `cells` are already double values, the rest gets coerced.

Comment: @Matt Even when I convert everything to double in the functions it still throws the error.

Comment: What text are you trying to parse that causes the exception?

Comment: @Taylor text from the temperature/temperature1 JTextFields

Comment: Lord.  Complete the following: I tried to parse the string `________` as an integer but it threw a number format exception.

Comment: @Taylor Sorry if I'm being irritating. I'm just frustrated and confused.

I tried to parse the String 'text' as an integer. 'text' references 'temperature'. When I parse the String 'text' as a Double value it still throws the error.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I read the article and thanks for that. I agree with it because I tried the JInternalFrame and JDialog methods and just got more and more frustrated until I just came back to the JFrame method. That's not my issue though, the frames display perfectly fine

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of your excepetion? (So that we see which line exactly is causing the error)

Answer (score 2):

You declare `double` values, and then try to parse them with `Integer`. An integer is, by any definition, a number with no decimal place. So when Java encounters any decimal place in your input, it will fail. Instead, you should be trying to parse them using `Double`.

For example:

```
    double d1, d2;
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Parsing d1...");
        d1 = Integer.parseInt("5.4");    // using Integer to parse a double fails
        System.out.println("d1: " + d1);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e1)
    {
        System.err.println("exception parsing 5.4 as an integer");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        System.out.println("Parsing d2...");
        d2 = Double.parseDouble("5.4");    // using Double to parse a double succeeds
        System.out.println("d2: " + d2);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e2)
    {
        System.err.println("exception parsing 5.4 as a double");
        e2.printStackTrace();
    };
```

Output:

```
Parsing d1...
exception parsing 5.4 as an integer
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5.4"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at pkg.Main.main(Main.java:40)
Parsing d2...
d2: 5.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I changed the parse to double as well in accordance to your try-catch example but it still decided not to work and pull an exception.

Comment: My bad, I got distracted with life. I solved the problem, it was a variable issue in the listener